# Bootstrap Thumbnail Slider does not display more than 4 Pictures in a row

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, slider

I found a responsive slider and I would like to add more than 4 pictures in a row. I cant find any definition for it. Is the class limited? Any help would be highly appreciated, thanks.

http://www.bootply.com/sBLPbGEgd5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the class is not limited. You need to understand how Bootstrap columns work. It lays them out in a grid of 12. In your example, you have this tag: `class="col-md-3"`, so each item takes up `3/12` of the space provided. If you want more than 4 items, you need to do the math. Try: `class="col-md-2"` instead of `class="col-md-3"`, that should allow you 5 items.

Example:
http://www.bootply.com/AkqtVYGOyf